# iOS App Preview videos - are all 3 iPhone resolutions required

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore, preview, app-store-connect

I've just completed an App Preview video for my forthcoming universal iOS app. I did it by capturing an iPhone 6 using QuickTime then editing in iMovie.

If I only submit my iPhone 6 App Preview video (750x1334), will iPhone 5/5s and 6 Plus users be able to see the video on the App Store?

Or do I have to create and upload separate iPhone 5/5s & iPhone 6 Plus videos?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I only uploaded 3 videos - iPhone 5 resolution, iPhone 6 resolution and iPad resolution. When I visited the app on the App Store on an iPhone 6 PLUS - the iPhone 6 video was shown.

So it looks like larger iPhones will fallback to smaller videos if the larger preview video is not present. Presumably the iPhone 6 will fallback to the iPhone 5 video as well.

Answer (score 1):

An App Preview is an optional short video demonstrating your app. **Your app may have one App Preview per device**. The specifications for App Previews are given in [App Preview Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW10).

Source: [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html)

Comment: Thanks, but my question is - if I only upload one single video for one device resolution (in this case the iPhone 6) - will iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 Plus users also be able to see this video when they browse the app on the App Store? Or will they not see an App Preview video at all (only the screenshots). I can't seem to find an answer to this within the Apple documentation.

Comment: No, if you upload only one video, only that device will have it available.

Comment: @DannyConnell, please accept the answer if you resolved what you want, which I'm sure you did.

Comment: Is it true (as in confirmed by someone who has actually done this for real) that the iPhone 6 Plus produces 1920x1080 resolution when screen-recording it in Yosemite?

Comment: You just paraphrased Apple's documentation, which everyone can read themselves, and which is totally unclear, which is why the question was asked in the first place. That means your answer is totally useless. And your comment is contradicted by by another answer, so that is not useless, it is wrong.